# What's behind the 'system' function in Perl?

Tags: perl

I can thought that it will open a shell, execute the parameter (shell command) and return the result in a scalar.
But, execute [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function in a Perl script is faster than a shell command.
It will call this command in C?
If yes, what's the difference between

```
rmdir foo
```

and

```
system('rmdir foo');
```

Comment: try not to call system commands unnecessarily, unless its proprietary and Perl doesn't have a module/API yet. To remove directories, use Perl's own rmdir(). Much of OS's system commands can be done in Perl itself

Comment: You can read the documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org. The entry for system answers this. It's fine to ask qeustions about docs you don't understand, but at least try yourself first :)

Comment: Also, you can read more about the different sorts of Perl interaction in last weeks post to The Effective Perler: http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/150

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The difference between the two is that the second one will open (fork) a child process (which will be the rmdir command) while the first one will make a direct Unix system call using the API without opening a process. Opening child process is **expensive** resource wise.
2. `system()` call will always open a child process to execute, BUT, it may either open a shell which will in turn fork off the desired program as its own child process (thus resulting in 2 child processes), or fork off the program as a child process directly.

   The choice of when Perl will open a shell during a `system()` call is spelled out in [perldoc -f system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). The short (and not 100% accurate) version is:

   - If there is only one parameter to system call, and the parameter evaluates to a string that contains shell meta-characters, a shell will be forked first.
   - If there's only one parameter and it evaluates to no metacharacters; or there's a >1 element list of parameters, the program is forked directly bypassing shell.

Thus:

```
system("rmdir foo"); # forks off rmdir command directly

system("rmdir", "foo"); # forks off rmdir command directly

system("rmdir foo > out.txt"); # forks off a shell because of ">"
```

Comment: For this kind of system call 'system("rmdir foo > out.txt");' it will be better to use a Shell Script! no?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa  - if that's the only line in a program, yes.

If that's 1 line out of 50 lines of Perl code which would take 500 lines of equivalent shell script, no. If that's 1 line out of a web app, and you decide to write the web app in shell script, I pity you and your employer :)

Answer (score 5):

Your `system` call starts a separate process while Perl's own `rmdir` will call the native C function in the context of the Perl process. Both methods end up doing the same system calls, but opening a new process is less efficient.*

It's best practice to use Perl's own functions (such as `rmdir`): they are portable, and you don't have to worry about interpreting shell exit codes, escaping metacharacters in filenames to prevent security risks, etc.

*`system` will create an additional `sh` process if your command contains pipes, input/output redirection, `&&` etc. This does not apply in your case, but can make the `system` option even slower.